how to prevent "git pull --rebase --autostash" from always updating timestamps of locally-modified files?
when I do git pull --rebase --autostash and have a locally-modified file, git always updates the timestamp of that file even if no commits touch that file (also even if no commits are actually pulled).
if that locally-modified file is a commonly-used header, eg, then that triggers a full-rebuild.
how do I do a pull like this without touching locally-modified files?

Maybe temporarily commit the local changes, rebase as normal, then reset off the temporary commit?

that would also touch the local files.


how do I do a pull like this without touching locally-modified files?

I don't think it's possible to achieve exactly what you want. The reason is because of how --autostash works. The documentation states:

--autostash
Automatically create a temporary stash entry before the operation begins, record it in the ref MERGE_AUTOSTASH and apply it after the operation ends. This means that you can run the operation on a dirty worktree. However, use with care: the final stash application after a successful merge might result in non-trivial conflicts.

The first sentence highlights that your locally modified file is going to be stashed before the pull operation happens, which is why it rewrites the file regardless of whether any commits will be pulled, or if that file will be modified. After the pull it rewrites the file again by grabbing the stashed version. Therefore, the file modification timestamp is going to change, twice.
